# Probability Distributions of Independent Random Variables

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I am currently taking a module in statistics but I have difficulty understanding this question. I do have the solution but I can hardly understand it. Can a kind soul please explain to me the solutions especially the one I marked with "WHY???". It'll be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**Let X and Y be independent random variables each having the uniform density on {0, 1, ..., N }.**

**Find the probability distributions of the following:**

**1) max(X,Y)**

**2) |Y −X|**

Solution:

P[max(x,y) < k]

= P[max(x,y) < k]

= P(x< k) n (y < k)] ** **WHY???**

= P[x < k] P[y < k] (since x and y are independent)  **  **WHY???**

= (R+1)/(N+1) x (R+1)/(N+1) (since x,y are uniform on {0,...,N)

Hence,

P[max(x,y)=k]

=P[max(x,y) < k] - P[max(x,y) < k-1]

=[(k+1)/(N+1)]^2 - [k/(N+1)]^2

= (2k+1)/(N+1)^2, where k=0,1,...,N

Thank you very very much!!

Comment: If you have the solutions which is hard to understand you can write the solution and point out your doubt, then you can get much help!

Comment: hi baymax! thank you for responding! and yes, I just did post the solution above, where I put WHY??? in the solution

Comment: do help if you're able to. thank you. and you didn't have to mark this question down... :(

Comment: With truth I was not the one to mark it down.BTW in future while asking questions and answering them do write your steps so that the potential users can exactly identify where is the problem and by this you get benifitted , also secondly do use Mathjax,Latex while writing Mathematical expressions [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: oh, oops. I'm sorry!! and thank you for the advice. it's my first time... and I'm kinda desperate for help. but thank you!

Comment: No problem,but you can find a lot of similar questions here [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=max%28X%2CY%29+probability)

Comment: Its recommended that you use $\LaTeX$ so that your questions are better received by the community..;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your **WHY** statement only,then we have

If there are two independent events say $A$ and $B$ ,Then $P(A \cap B) = P(A) P(B)$(?) ,

? - Because,think of **conditional probability** $P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{ P(B)}$ since $P(A|B) =P(A)$ [*occurence of event $B$ doesnot affect the occurence of event $A$*] and hence $P(A \cap B) = P(A) P(B)$

**EDIT** -

*) No problem,but you can find a lot of similar questions here [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=max%28X%2CY%29+probability)

*) For the edited **WHY?** - well think of a number line!  suppose $max(x,y)  = x$ then $P(x < k)$,now as $x < k$ , you must see $y < x < k$ that is both $x < k$ and $y<k$! similar thing can be done if you consider $max(x,y) = y$

Comment: this is great! thank you!! you guys make it so clear.

Comment: if you don't mind, I have another question as well

= P[max(x,y) < k]

= P(x< k) n (y < k)]

why this step?

Comment: well think of a number line!  suppose $max(x,y)  = x$ then $P(x < k)$,now as $x < k$ , you must see $y < x < k$ that is both $x < k$ and $y<k$! similar thing can be done if you consider $max(x,y) = y$

Comment: oh... but why is y < x? it isn't mentioned, is it? or did I miss that out?

Comment: OH WAIT.... I think I'm getting it!! because if the maximum between x and y is x, then of course y is < x!! right..?

Comment: Yes,as $max(x,y) $ can be either $x$ or $y$ , we took two cases and observe!

Comment: WOW thank you so much baymax! you're indeed baymax- such a great helper and teacher! greatly appreciated (:

Comment: another quick question... if you are so kind to respond... that is from the very beloved respondent above. what if it's min(x,y) - does that apply too?

Comment: Aw, Again think of a number line what happens if $P(min(X,Y) > k)$ ? then that corresponds to P(X > k) P(Y > k)!

Comment: ahh okay! I roughly had that in mind actually... just wasn't that confident. but really, thank you so much for your help. I'm understanding this module much better now. #grateful

Comment: Also @WangFei you may take a look at the various questions similar to this i posted as a link in my answer, also there is a chat room dedicted to  [Probability and Statistics](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65689/probability-and-statistics),I admit that it is not much active though,perhaps posting in some questions might gain attention to the room to have  a good discussion!

Comment: oh wow thank you for the invite! I was about to post one more... thank you thank you thank you but aww, unfortunately I do not have enough reputations to chat :( I'll work my way up!

Comment: Some other time! after you are a bit comfortable with MSE site! see you then1

Comment: sure! will definitely learn more about MSE!

Comment: Also do rememer that you can mark any answer as your accepted answer by clicking a green tick and also upvote it,its for the good for you and other potential users as it says that the user has understood the answer!

Comment: GOT IT! THANK YOU TOO!!

Answer (score 0):

If $X,Y$ are independent random variables then events like $\{X\in A\}$ and $\{Y\in B\}$ are [independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#Two_events).

Consequently: $$P(X\in A\wedge Y\in B)=P(\{X\in A\}\cap\{Y\in B\})=P(\{X\in A\})P(\{Y\in B\})=P(X\in A)P(Y\in B)$$

Comment: ahh! I see! thank you for the clear explanation!

then I have another question if you don't mind!

= P[max(x,y) < k]

= P(x< k) n (y < k)]

why is this so?

Comment: It starts with $\max(X,Y)<k\iff X<k\wedge Y<k$ purely on base of the definition of $\max$ (is that clear?). So the expressions $\max(X,Y)<k$ and $X<k\wedge Y<k$ describe the same event. Then the probability of this event is $P(\max(X,Y)<k)$ and is also $P(X<k\wedge Y<k)$.

Comment: yes absolutely clear! I love it when it is "based on definition". then what if it's min(x,y)? I suppose it's different right?